# アナログ・デジタルフィルタの併用は邪道かどうか

Tags: c

圧力センサ(FlexiForce)の出力信号をマイコン(RX631)でAD変換してデータを取得していますが、
**ノイズがひどい**(信号の約40%)ので以下のフィルタをかけています。

- アナログフィルタ → 2次、カットオフ周波数1Hz
- デジタルフィルタ → 1次バターワース、カットオフ周波数1Hz、C言語

この2つのフィルタで取得した信号はノイズが除去されており、数値も静的な計測では正確です。

このように、アナログ・デジタルフィルタを併用するのは産業・研究分野では普通のことなのか、邪道なのかを知りたいです。(併用は避けるべきと聞いたことがあるので)
どなたかご教授下さい。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

それ以外にノイズを除去するすべがない＝併用する必要があるとあなたが・上司が判断したのであれば、併用することに問題はないでしょう。

> 静的な計測では正確

ってことは要するに高速に変化する信号は読めないってことですから、あとはその辺が「要求される案件」に合致するか否かってことで。

---

ない袖は振れぬ、つまりノイズに埋もれた信号は拾うすべがないので、高速に変化する信号が拾いたいのであれば、ハードウエアレベルでのノイズ対策が絶対に先です。ハードウエアでの対策ができたなら、ソフトによる対策を併用するまでもないわけです。

逆も真で、ソフトウェアでノイズフィルタして応用目的にかなうのであれば、わざわざハードウエアにお金をかけて「対策」しなくてもいいでしょう。

> 併用は避けるべき

そういう意味で「併用」する必然が無いと、この文章は読むべきです。

だから両方しないと目的が達せられないのなら、両方で対策することをためらう必要はありません。